# Remove redundant disable/enable key statements from mysqldump

Tags: mysql, locking, mysqldump

A standard mysqldump will create a table, disable keys, insert the data, and re-enable keys. There are reasons for this. However, when a table is empty, the keys are still disabled and re-enabled.

```
LOCK TABLES `Brands` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Brands` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Brands` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This little block of code, repeated multiple times, is surely slowing down inserts for no good reason. Is there any way to remove it, or to prevent its creation in the first place? I imagine that it is no big deal, but I’m still curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry, `DISABLE KEYS` and `ENABLE KEYS` are artifacts from mysqldump of bygone days

These commands, `DISABLE KEYS` and `ENABLE KEYS` have absolutely no effect on InnoDB Tables (they were not implemented for the InnoDB Storage Engine). They were designed specifically for MyISAM tables. You will just get warnings.

[I have written about this many times as far back as May 2011](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=user%3A877%20DISABLE%20KEYS&searchOn=3)

[See MySQL Documentation on this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html)

You can create dumps without them with

```
mysqldump ... | grep -v "ABLE KEYS" > dumpfile.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html says:

> For MyISAM tables, key updating can be controlled explicitly. Use `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS` to tell MySQL to stop updating nonunique indexes. Then use `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS` to re-create missing indexes. MyISAM does this with a special algorithm that is much faster than inserting keys one by one, so disabling keys before performing bulk insert operations should give a considerable speedup.

In other words, this is a performance *advantage* if you are restoring data to MyISAM tables. How much of an advantage is hard to predict, because it depends on how many indexes you have in your table, and other factors such as the performance of your server.

As Rolando wrote in his answer, it has no effect for InnoDB tables, and in my opinion, we should all use the InnoDB storage engine by default.  I haven't found any good reason to use MyISAM tables in many years.

Comment: *I haven't found any good reason to use MyISAM tables in many years*, there are still systems using MyISAM, ViciDial for example. I opened a thread on ViciDial forum on [Switching ViciDial tables from MyISAM to InnoDB](http://www.vicidial.org/VICIDIALforum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=41633)

Comment: @ErgestBasha, I wonder why they don't they use [locking reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) in cases where they need to serialize access to the table?

Comment: honestly I do not know.  My guess , it is an enormous job to do as there are plenty of scripts which needs changes.

Comment: That sounds like it will take some some coding experience. I wonder if they have anyone who has coding experience?

Comment: Based on my experience surely they need a DBA , maybe both DBA/programmer . A lot of  queries needs performance improvement , sometimes data normalization is needed. If you are curios about the code behind Vicidial you can download [Asterisk GUI client, VICIdial](https://sourceforge.net/projects/astguiclient/) , see inside the downloaded archive on \www\vicidial  and \www\agc . Maybe there are a lot of improvements which can be done and you can suggest to the ViciDial guys .

Comment: Anyway, my point remains: I don't think there's any good reason to use MyISAM. The fact that some people continue to use MyISAM out of lack of expertise with InnoDB isn't a reason for a new project to use MyISAM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--skip-disable-keys` flag to exclude those lines, eg:

```
mysqldump --skip-disable-keys -u foo -p bar.sql
```

This Medium post is a great resource: [mysqldump Cheat Sheet](https://jeewantha-abayakoon.medium.com/mysqldump-cheat-sheet-5cba8ca47927)